# Django - Datetime range end time excluded

Tags: python, django, datetime

I did a form to allow users to add `absences` consisting of datetime ranges.

[image: datetime range editor]

I left the time optional, so they can set for example `2014-01-23` to `2014-01-24`

But since the final stored values will be `2014-01-23 00:00:00` to `2014-01-24 00:00:00`, this range will actually cover only the 23rd. Most likely the user will want us to consider `2014-01-25 00:00:00` instead for the end.

Is it a good idea to store these datetimes this manner ?

Should I automatically increment the end date if end time is not set ?

---

**Update**

Following @MartijnPieters advice, here is how I checked wether `end_time` was empty

```py
def clean_end_time(self):
    end_dt = self.cleaned_data.get('end_time', None)
    if end_dt.time().min == end_dt.time():
        return datetime.combine(end_dt, end_dt.time().max)
    return self.cleaned_data.get('end_time', None)
```

The only small issue will be that the user can't select `00:00` as `end_time` on purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the end time to `23:59:59.999999` if the time is not set, instead.

Now your datetime range goes from `2014-01-23 00:00:00` through to `2014-01-24 23:59:59.999999`, 1 microsecond before `2014-01-25` (which is *not* part of the range).

Your can use [`datetime.time.max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.max) to provide this value:

```
end = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(2014, 1, 24), datetime.time.max)
```

Comment: This would be better indeed. I'll try that.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can check if the time is not set ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY: leave the value entirely empty instead of filling in a default, *or* set a default time of `23:59`.

Comment: Well the thing is I'm receiving the datetime already converted into `clean_end_time()` so it gets set to `2014-01-25 00:00:00`

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY: Then you'll have to implement your own clean hook. :-)

Comment: I think I'll simply compare the received `end_date` with `end_date.time().min` then set it to `max` if True